かったとする? What does it mean?
丁度彼がおりてくる。
めぼしい物はなかったとする、気怠く砕けた足取りだった。
I understand the sentence is describing how the person arrives after descending the stairs but what does なかったとする here mean? The rest is like languid and informal steps.

This とする means "to say/state/report". It takes the previous sentence (めぼしい物はなかった).

What does this としています express?
What is the difference between として and とする?
Is this volitional +とする?
What does 過去へ遡るほど大きいとされる refers to here?


めぼしい物はなかったとする、気怠く砕けた足取りだった。
It was a languid and disjointed walk, suggesting there was nothing worth noting.


Hmm, する really is "lighter" than I thought. Although it's not as hard for me to understand as 付く.
